# $dirty and validation directive for non input elements (ie, elements with contentEditable)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, contenteditable

I am using AngularJS 1.3.8.
I am using span tags with contentEditable = true to edit some fields inline.
But I don't know how to use the $dirty, ng-minlength like validation attributed with span tags.
Can anybody tell me how can I do that?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561676/angularjs-and-contenteditable-two-way-binding-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: Two way data binding is working for me. but the $dirty, $prestine etc and validation are not working.

Comment: probably you need write your own directive, and `$setValidity` of `ngModel`

Comment: hmm. OK.thank you for the reply. Will try to write one